# ?Using a sql cursor in a html select tag

Tags: javascript, html, plsql

I am creating a procedure in oracle where I am using HTML to display a drop down list that refers to a database. I thought of using a cursor to point to a ID which refers to rows in a database and I wanted the user to select what ever referred row (by ID) to click a button to delete it from the database, but first I wanted to be able to create the cursor that refers to the ID in the database and let it be shown through a select drop down list. Here is my code

How would I populate the select tag with data from sql database using either sql or javascript. no php or jquery? please

```
 procedure ALFRED_DELETE
    IS
    CURSOR c1
    IS
       SELECT EMPID
       FROM ALFRED_FORM_TABLE
       WHERE course_name = name_in;
     BEGIN

    htp.p('
    <html>


         <select>
         <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>

         </select>


         </table>


         <input type ="submit" name="SubmitInfo" value="Submit Information"/>

       </form>

    </table>



</html>

');

  end ALFRED_DELETE;
```

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: How would I populate the select tag with data from a sql database using only javascript or sql

Answer (score 0):

Try looping through the values of the cursor then fetch the id you need via conditional statement. then simply concatenate it as a value of the select tag.

```
procedure ALFRED_DELETE
IS
    l_id number;

    CURSOR c1
    IS
       SELECT EMPID
       FROM ALFRED_FORM_TABLE
       WHERE course_name = name_in;

BEGIN

    OPEN c1;
    LOOP
      FETCH c1 INTO l_id;
      EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;

      if l_id = (the_value_i_need) then
        exit;
      end if;
    END LOOP;

    htp.p('
    <html>


         <select>
         <option value="volvo">' || l_id || '</option>

         </select>


         </table>


         <input type ="submit" name="SubmitInfo" value="Submit Information"/>

       </form>

    </table>



    </html>  
    ');

    CLOSE c1;
end ALFRED_DELETE;
```